# Freezing/repeating the last frame of a video clip in Apple Motion 5

Tags: video, video-editor, motion

I have two clips running at the same time. One is a computer and the other is a clip that I've made to look like its running on the computer screen. I've used four corner motion tracker to keep the two in sync as the computer clip zooms in.

At a certain point i'd like to freeze the computer clip while the clip on its screen plays out. I can crop the computer clip up to the point I want it frozen but I'm unsure of how to extend/repeat that last frame so it stays visible until the other clip finishes. At the moment it just dissapears when it hits the crop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, figured out how to do this. Make sure you location is at the frame you want to freeze, hide all the other layers in Motion to just show the video that you want to freeze.

Then go Share menu > Save Current Frame. Then save that image somewhere.

All you have to do then is import that image back in and place it again at the end of the clip it came from. Ensure it's lower in the layer stack so that other clips appear on top of it until they disappear - or just crop it.

Comment: OMG thank you this is a perfect solution to something I was trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

That is not a good solution. 
With this solution you are now locked at the size and position of your window, not the source media.  If you want to zoom in or out you have now lost that ability.

Better solution is to use the timing controls and set the end condition to "Hold"